# Как программно заполнить в чужом окне поле ввода и нажать на кнопку?

Tags: delphi

Как программно заполнить в чужом окне поле ввода и нажать на кнопку?

Осталось доделать: 1) заполнение темы письма (может даже решается и не программно, а настройками), 2) нажать кнопку отправить.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Для посылки окну клавиатурных и мышиных событий можно пользоваться [SendInput API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/ms646310(v=vs.85).aspx). Пример для левого клика мышью:

```
var
inputs: array [0..1] of TInput;
begin
    ZeroMemory(@inputs, sizeof(inputs));
    inputs[0].Itype := INPUT_MOUSE;
    inputs[0].mi.dwFlags :=MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN;
    inputs[1].Itype := INPUT_MOUSE;
    inputs[1].mi.dwFlags :=MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP;
    SendInput(2, inputs[0], sizeof(TInput));
end;
```

Фокус ввода уже должен быть на элементе.

Comment: я думаю мне бы сначала найти поле ввода и кнопку на форме .... а посылать это уже следующий этап. подсказали такое SetWindowText для установки, но пока не въезжаю, смотрю что и как.